# Cloud Firestore query flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a set of document that's stored in cloud firestore. Each document is associated with the users uid that is retrieved from firebase auth.

Now I want to show the posts the users have uploaded in there profile section. Any Idea of how to do this?

Method to get the users uid

```
String userID = '';

getUserUID() async{
  FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  userID = user.uid.toString();
  return userID;
}
```

The code for querying the data.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Music').where('uid', isEqualTo: userID.toString()).snapshots(),
```

Note: if I replace the userID.toString() with the actuall uid it shows the required results.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `await` in from of a method does not magically make it synchronous. If you call `` before your query, you'll still need to `await` that call too.

The simplest fix is:

```
Firestore.instance
         .collection('Music')
         .where('uid', isEqualTo: await getUserUID()).snapshots(),
```

Comment: this throws an error: StreamBuilder(
                stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Music').where('uid', isEqualTo:await getUserUID()).snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot)

Comment: It would be helpful to see what the error is in that case. Also: did you search for the error message already?

Comment: so it tells await is an unexpected text 'await', try removing the text.

Comment: It sounds like the function that you use this code is is not marked as `async`, which is required in order to be able to use `await` in it.

Comment: so where would I add the async function? That's the part I am having difficulty in. I can share the whole code if you like